# Eloquent Relationship with a conditional scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on a Fantasy sports app. The models I am working with are FantasyPlayer, PlayerGame, TeamGame

FantasyPlayer can have many PlayerGame and can have many TeamGame

```php
public function PlayerGame()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PlayerGame','player_id','player_id');
}

public function TeamGame()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FantasyData\TeamGame','team','fantasy_player_key');
}
```

When I load the data I use eager loading currently:

```php
FantasyPlayer::with(['PlayerGame', 'TeamGame'])->take(1)->get();
```

It is becoming tedious to load both relationships and then which are loaded. Ideally, I want to have the model handle this logic for. So I would be able to do something like this:

```php
FantasyPlayer::with(['FantasyGame'])->take(1)->get();
```

Then my FantasyGame scope would contain either the PlayerGame or the TeamGame record I need based on an a FantasyPlayer value for the position. Something like this is what I want... but it doesn't work for me:

```php
public function scopeFantasyGame($query)
{
    if($this->position == "DEF"){
      return $this->TeamGame();
    }
    else{
      return $this->PlayerGame();
    }
 }
```

Does anyone know  way I could use eager loading and have the FantasyGame return the correct relationship based on a FantasyPlayer position attribute?:

```php
FantasyPlayer::with(['FantasyGame'])->take(1)->get();
```

Comment: You've not provided enough information to be sure, but this sounds like it could be a good candidiate for using Laravel [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Comment: If you are only returning 1 result is there a need for the eager loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## #1

You can't eager load relationships conditionally based on the result elements, this because the eager loading happens before you retrieve the records, that's why this won't work:

```
# FantasyPlayer.php

public function scopeFantasyGame($query)
{
    if($this->position == "DEF") // <--- Laravel doens't retrieve the records yet,
    {                            //      so this won't work
      //
    }
    else
    {
      // 
    }
 }
```

## #2

[Local Query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) are used to constraint queries, in your case you want to load relationships with this scope, not its general purpose but sure you could do it:

```
# FantasyPlayer.php

public function scopeFantasyGame($query)
{
    return $query->with(['PlayerGame', 'TeamGame']);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
# YourController.php

public function myFunction($query)
{
    $fantasyPlayers = FantasyPlayer::fantasyGame()->get();
}
```

## #3

But then, if you want to always eager load the relationships, why use a query scope and not just tell laravel to load your desired relationships by default? You could do specify it in your model (check the *Eager Loading By Default* of [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the docs):

```
# FantasyPlayer.php

protected $with = ['PlayerGame', 'TeamGame'];
```

---

## Update

If you want to retrieve elements that always have a given relationship, you have two paths. For the first one, you could use a query scope to only load those elements:

```
# FantasyPlayer.php

public function scopeHasFantasyGame($query)
{
    return $query
              ->has('PlayerGame')
              ->has('TeamGame');
}
```

Then:

```
# YourController.php

public function myFunction($query)
{
    $fantasyPlayers = FantasyPlayer::hasFantasyGame()->get();
}
```

The second option would be to retrieve the elements, then filter the collection based on the existence of the relationship (using the [Map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) function):

```
# YourController.php

public function myFunction($query)
{
    $fantasyPlayers = FantasyPlayer::all()
                          ->map(function ($fantasyPlayer) {
                              return $fantasyPlayer->PlayerGame()->exists()
                                     && $fantasyPlayer->TeamGame()->exists();
                          });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation - it is clearer now. The default eager loading sounds pretty good and will help in the long run. In that scenario, I still need to do some logic checking to see which relationship has data (PlayerGame or TeamGame).  However, my final goal is to be able to call FantasyPlayer->FantasyGame() and always know that FantasyGame contains the record that I need (PlayerGame or TeamGame). It may not be possible with eager loading though.

Comment: Well, you have two ways to do that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you again for the great example code and information! This will help me tremendously!

Comment: @thindery glad to help.